# android : set/ getArgument fails in fragment

Tags: android

I am tyring to add a fragment in a navigation Drawer and some of the data have to pass to the fragment,
but getArgument returns null and I still cannot solve the problem after reading the similar question.

In my drawer class, the fragment is added by

```
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("username",username);
                args.putString("password",password);

                UserLoginFragment alreadyLoginFragment = new UserLoginFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                alreadyLoginFragment.setArguments(args);
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.drawer_User_Container, alreadyLoginFragment, "alreadyLogin");
                fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

;

And in the fragment, the argument is get by :

```
    String username;
    String password;
    public UserLoginFragment(){
        Bundle args=getArguments();
        if(args!=null){
            Log.d("test","have args");
        }
        else{
            Log.d("test","no args");
        }
    }
```

And the log will be no args

Comment: Probably you need to call getArgument() method in onCreateView method of fragment I instead of in constructor

Comment: Fragments `onCreate` methods are called inside the transaction, which happens after you set the arguments. The constructor happens before you can even set the arguments. In conclusion reading args in constructor will never work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont call `getArgument()` in the constructor, at the time the constructor is called, the argument bundle has not yet been set, so it will return `null` every time no matter what you do. Call it like this

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity act)
{
    Bundle args = getArguments();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just recieving the argument. You must recieve the content that was passed in the argument.

```
String username = getArguments().getString("username");
String password = getArguments().getString("password");
```

Comment: getArgument will work when commit is called not during creating object of class which extends Fragment